# Drawing triangle doesn't work: I just see a black screen and my mouse

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm using GLEW for modern OpenGL functions and GLFW for the window. I'm trying to draw a triangle but something is wrong it compile and runs but doesn't draw the triangle, I just see a black screen and my mouse.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <glm\glm.hpp>

const GLchar* vertexSource =
"#version 150 core\n"
"in ver2 position;"
"void main(){"
"   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
"}";

const GLchar* fragmentSource =
"#version 150 core\n"
"out vec4 outColor;"
"void main(){"
"   outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);"
"}";

int main(){

    //GLFW init:
    if (!glfwInit()){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to init GLFW");
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    //Hints:
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    //Creating window:
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Engine", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //Glew initialize:
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    //Create vertex array object:
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    //Create vertex buffer object:
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    //Our triangle data:
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
         0.0f,  0.5f, //Vertex 1 (X, Y)
         0.5f, -0.5f, //Vertex 2 (X, Y)
        -0.5f, -0.5f  //Vertex 3 (X, Y)
    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Create and compile the vertex shader:
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    //Create and compile the fragment shader:
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    //Creating shaders program:
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);



    //The loop:
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){

        //Escape key:
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS){
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
        }

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"in ver2 position;"
    ^^^^
```

What's a `ver2`?  I doubt your GLSL compiler knows either.

Try `vec2` and checking your shader compilation/link status/logs:

```
struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* vert, const char* geom, const char* frag )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        if( vert ) AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert );
        if( geom ) AttachShader( prog, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, geom );
        if( frag ) AttachShader( prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE;
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        GLchar log[ 1 << 15 ] = { 0 };
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        std::cerr << log << std::endl;
        exit( -1 );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow I can't belive this was the problem.. ty.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `glBindFragDataLocation`, instead write to `gl_FragColor` in the fragment shader:

```
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
"#version 150 core\n"
"void main(){"
"   gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);"
"}";
```

otherwise you need to specify which buffer it is written to with `glDrawBuffers`

Comment: The poster is using the core profile, where `gl_FragColor` is deprecated. But the `glBindFragDataLocation` call isn't needed anyway. If a fragment shader has only one `out`, it's automatically written to the first draw buffer (which by default is `GL_BACK` for the default framebuffer, and `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` for FBOs).

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Actually, I never could find such a guarantee in the spec. All the spec says is that the GL will automatically assign any outputs where the location is not manuyally assigned to some unused color number. Every real-world implementation starts assignment with 0, for obvious reasons, but relying on that is still undefined behavior as far as the spec goes.

Comment: @derhass: It's specified. GLSL 4.4 spec: "If an output variable with no location or index assigned in the shader text has a location specified through the OpenGL API, the API-assigned location will be used.  Otherwise, such variables will be assigned a location by the linker.  All such assignments will have a color index of zero." ES 3.0 GLSLS spec: "If there is only a single output, the location does not need to be specified, in which case it defaults to zero."

Comment: @RetoKoradi: actually, it is not. I made the same mistake by myself earlier: there is a difference between the color _number_, and the color _index_. The color _number_ is the relevant part here. The _index_ is just for multi-input blending. Note that it would also be weird if the spec would require that all of the outputs (if more than one is used) would be bound to the same number 0... The ES 3.0 spec is a different thing, though.

Comment: @derhass: Ok, yes, I see what you're saying. It's indeed not explicitly specified that the linker would assign the locations starting at 0. There's a lot of software that would break if a driver didn't handle it that way, but you're theoretically right. The ES reference matters because they try very hard to keep the ES specs to be a subset of full OpenGL. So if behavior is guaranteed in ES, but not in OpenGL, that would be very undesirable.